# 'Undefined' error in logs when deploying Firebase Realtime Database Triggers

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy the following Firebase Database Trigger:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

try { 
  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("dbMessagesUpdate initializeApp failure");
}

exports.onMessagesUpdate = functions.database.ref("/messages/basic_message").onCreate((snap, context) => {
console.log("SNAP: ", snap.val());
});
```

From the command line with:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

But keep getting the following error in the logs:

```
2018-09-10T16:24:15.543Z I : undefined
2018-09-10T16:24:20.037Z N onMessagesUpdate: undefined
2018-09-10T16:24:59.432Z N onMessagesUpdate: undefined
```

I can see the function on the firebase console, but it fails to fire when I create entries under /messages/basic_message

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This database trigger:

```
functions.database.ref("/messages/basic_message").onCreate(...)
```

only fires when /messages/basic_message is created for the first time.  If it already exists with children, the trigger will not fire.

Also, those log messages are not errors.  You might be using an old version of firebase-tools or firebase-functions that dropped empty messages into the log.

Also, the way you are initializing the admin SDK is deprecated.  You should just be doing this instead:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

And there's no need for try/catch.